# Jquery calculate minimum required height value of a div

Tags: jquery, html, height

Currently i am setting absolute height values. But sometimes i am being have to set a lot higher than required because of dynamic pages. Is it possible to get minimum required height of div ? i mean the height value which will show all the elements like height auto but no empty spaces will left.
I can't set height auto because it causes too much mess. I tried and failed.

**So jquery will read the div and calculate minimum required height value for displaying all elements. Is this possible ?**

Thank you.

Comment: If you need your heights to be dynamic would it not be easier to not set an absolute height at all and just let the div size itself naturally?

Comment: well i tried that but it fails :D i was messing around for hours now but can't achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Clive said, there is usually no reason to do this. However, if you need to get height of all inside elements, you can use something like this:

```
var height = 0;
$.each($("your_div").children(), function(i,v) {
    height += $(v).outerHeight(true);
});
console.log(height);
```

Function outerHeight(true) counts height of the element including border and margin. See http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/ for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can also wrap the elements inside another div.

```
<div class="toResize">
    <div>
        <element1 />
        <element2 />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, only resize the outer-most div (.toResize).  If you need the minimum height, you can get it via

```
var minHeight = $(".toResize").children("div").height();
```

I hope that helps.